USB device not showing up in boot menu
I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my Windows laptop for dual boot option but the USB does not show up in the boot menu
I have been searching for a solution for several hours now and nothing I've found helps or relates to my specific issue.

The laptop is a Dell G7 and currently has Windows 11 installed. It is listed in the Ubuntu  certified systems though that's from 2021 and with Ubuntu 18.04, I don't know if that makes any difference.
I created the usb drive with Rufus.
The drive is formatted for UEFI, the stick is usb 3.0.
I have tried using the 3 different usb ports on the laptop and it does not show up on any in the boot menu.
I have tried creating drives with Ubuntu 24.04 and 22.04.4
I have used the usb on an older Thinkpad laptop and it has appeared in the boot menu and I was able to boot from it.
I have tried turning off fast startup as suggested elsewhere which did not help
I turned on Legacy options in the system menu and the USB did show up in the boot menu though I couldn't boot off it as it's UEFI, but it shows the USB is there!
I have gone through the list of suggestions on this page and none seem to be relevant: Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm not sure what else to try!
Thank you,
Fintan

Sounds like you have a hardware problem Unless the USB is working at the hardware level it can not be used to install the OS.

Do you have latest UEFI firmware and if NVMe drive latest firmware for it? Often Dell or Windows will update UEFI firmware in background, resetting UEFI settings to defaults. sudo dmidecode -s bios-version &
udisksctl status compare to vendor's support site.  My Dell worked as it only had NVMe drive and used a Intel® VMD driver. Always before we had to change drives from "RAID" to AHCI and add AHCI drivers into Windows for Windows to still work. Is Bitlocker off, and Windows fast startup/hibernation, different than UEFI fast boot which should be off when making system changes.

thank you for the replies. I don't know how it could be a hardware problem with the USB if it works on another laptop and shows up on the boot menu when Legacy options are turned on.
Regarding 'UEFI firmware and if NVMe drive latest firmware ' I don't know so will check that now

Some machines may want the USB present at shutdown before it will be seen at boot. Some machines may have a second level of boot order, "UEFI hard disks" which unexpectedly might include the USB disk. The Ubuntu ISOs boot both legacy and UEFI, but RUFUS may allow you to make a USB which can boot only one way -- check that the USB is really UEFI bootable.

You don't how the ISO was written, all QA of Ubuntu is done with simple clone writes of ISO to media; if you reformat it (via options in the ISO write software) you will make it bootable on only certain devices (esp. releases >20.04; you do mention 18.04 works! for example).  Did you validate ISO checksum before write?

Thanks for the suggestions. I managed to solve the issue by creating the boot drive using balenaEtcher - it was with the same USB drive and the same settings as rufus so not sure what the difference was, maybe it formats the drive differently, validates the ISO checksum and/or makes the USB UEFI bootable as mentioned by above?

Rufus needs updating to write ISOs >20.04 if you choose options to reformat the ISO; it may have been a user-created issue due to use of outdated rufus software (unless simple clone was used as that ISO write has never changed).  A clone write will not format the USB drive during write; it just clones ISO to media without format (thus written as intended & QA tested as format comes from ISO itself)

I managed to solve the issue by creating the boot drive using balenaEtcher rather than rufus. I don't know if that will be useful to anyone else but hopefully it helps someone else in need!
